# World To Screen Issue on Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having this extremely weird W2S issue on a Unity Game called SCP-SL.

I was trying to find a view matrix to make ESP which I found the right one and it allows me to draw a box perfectly. (Btw I am using a const Vec3 with an old player origin)

[text](https://ibb.co/FgXcFDr)

I debugged the w values and while facing the box as shown in the picture above W = 140 and for some reason even while going behind the box W was still positive and barely decreasing

As soon as I turn around the box never draws again which is obviously not good for ESP. After turning around and checking the values of W its in the negatives which doesnt correlate with other games ive worked on.

Here is a video of what it looks like.
[text](https://streamable.com/ss14d9)

Here is my w2s using a float[16] matrix

```
bool WorldToScreen(Vector3 pos, Vector2& screen, view_matrix_t vm, Screen res) {
Vector4 clipCoords;
clipCoords.x = pos.x * vm.matrix[0] + pos.y * vm.matrix[4] + pos.z * vm.matrix[8] + vm.matrix[12];
clipCoords.y = pos.x * vm.matrix[1] + pos.y * vm.matrix[5] + pos.z * vm.matrix[9] + vm.matrix[13];
clipCoords.z = pos.x * vm.matrix[2] + pos.y * vm.matrix[6] + pos.z * vm.matrix[10] + vm.matrix[14];
clipCoords.w = pos.x * vm.matrix[3] + pos.y * vm.matrix[7] + pos.z * vm.matrix[11] + vm.matrix[15];

if (clipCoords.w < 0.1f)
    return false;

Vector3 NDC;
NDC.x = clipCoords.x / clipCoords.w;
NDC.y = clipCoords.y / clipCoords.w;
NDC.z = clipCoords.z / clipCoords.w;

screen.x = (res.Width / 2 * NDC.x) + (NDC.x + res.Width / 2);
screen.y = -(res.Height / 2 * NDC.y) + (NDC.y + res.Height / 2);
return true; }
```

I am drawing in GDI btw, I doubt changing drawing libraries will fix the issue :/

EDIT: While facing the box when its drawing properly that entire direction is positive W another weird thing I noticed is that W actually has two different values, the first time it checks the value was 3.4 then the next call it was 140, so on so on

Tried messing with the w2s function/trying different ones and I couldnt get it to draw a box like this one.

Comment: Probably more of a question to ask on a unity forum.

Comment: This is not c++ code so i removed unnecessary tags